# How do I remove the popup about "The 'VSTS for Database Professionals' package did not load correctly."?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm not sure exactly when, my VS2010 started showing me the same error popup every time I loaded it. Clicking "No" has no effect, since the message will show up again each and every time I open VS.

I really don't see any adverse effect without this "VSTS for Database Professionals", but the error popup is getting annoying. Can anyone tell me how to disable it without having to uninstall anything?

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The 'VSTS for Database Professionals' package did not load correctly.



The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by running the application together with the /log parameter on the command line, and then examining the file 'C:\Users\peter.mounce\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ActivityLog.xml'.



Continue to show this error message?
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

Edited to add: I did a google search to see if anyone else had this problem, but the only cases are found are not applicable to my situation, since I have neither LightSwitch nor PostSharp installed.
I do have ReSharper 6.1, if it helps any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your log file, it appears Resharper is somehow interfering. Try uninstalling/repairing and seeing if that makes it better.

```
<entry>
    <record>288</record>
    <time>2013/04/11 18:30:06.996</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [VSTS for Database Professionals]</description>
    <guid>{068E2583-0872-403B-AF4C-6C2A8F2D8C3E}</guid>
    <hr>80131522</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'JetBrains.Platform.ReSharper.Util, Version=6.1.1000.82, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325'.</errorinfo>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have .NET Framework 4.5 installed? If not, installing that can help with this popup. I have not investigated why, but this package appears to depend on .NET Framework 4.5 for some reason. Even if using Visual Studio 2010 (which does not even support 4.5).

Comment: Did you try the /log option and look at the activitylog file as stated in the popup? If you want I can try and help analyze it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer, I hadn't realized you made another comment. This is my ActivityLog: http://pastebin.com/ZSeQeuz2

Answer (score 2):

1. Visual Studio 2010 installation media: \WCU\DAC folder, find and run-install:

   - DACFramework_enu.msi
   - DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi
   - TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi
2. Reapply Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Details:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532121/tons-of-package-did-not-load-correctly-errors

Comment: Worked great, and I didn't need to install 2010 SP1, just the three packages.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to reset the settings (in case something went wrong with the SQL side of installation):

1) Launch DOS in ADMIN mode (hold WindowsKey+X), Select "Command Prompt (Admin)"
2) Go to your developer studio folder, usually it's under "C:\Program File(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"
3) Reset the settings by typing:

> devenv.exe /ResetSettings

4) Once done, close DOS, and then launch Visual Studio, the error should disappear.